# Java regex contain 2 values (same value inside)

Tags: java, regex

```
String input = " Fa0/1     --- Cisco IP phone notconnected   20       a-full    auto    10/100BaseTX"
String DISABLED = "disabled";
String CONNECTED = "connected";
String NOTCONNECTED = "notconnected";    
String REGEXP_STATUS = "^(\\s*)(\\w+/\\d+|\\w+/\\d+/\\d+)(\\s+)(.*|\\*|-)(" + NOTCONNECTED + "|" + DISABLED + "|" + CONNECTED + ")(\\s+)(\\d+|trunk)(\\s+)(\\w+|a-\\w+)(\\s+)(\\w+|a-\\d+)(\\s+)(\\w+|/+).*";
```

My problem is `matcher.group(5)` return `CONNECTED` if input is `NOTCONNECTED` because **CONNECTED** word is in NOT**CONNECTED**

**EDIT:**

I try:

```
String REGEXP_STATUS = "^(\\s*)(\\w+/\\d+|\\w+/\\d+/\\d+)(\\s+)(.*|\\*|-)(" + DISABLED + "|.*" + CONNECTED + ")(\\s+)(\\d+|trunk)(\\s+)(\\w+|a-\\w+)(\\s+)(\\w+|a-\\d+)(\\s+)(\\w+|/+).*";
```

but `matcher.group(5)` return `CONNECTED` and `matcher.group(4)` return `--- Cisco IP phone not`

Comment: Maybe insert word boundaries when you are looking for "connected" vs "notconnected"?

Comment: `.*` is greedy, so it grabs everything until the end, then backtracks from there, and `connected` matches before `notconnected` while backtracking. Make it non-greedy, aka reluctant: `.*?`

Comment: *Curious:* Do you really need to capture the spaces?

Comment: @Andreas, no necessary

Comment: Even if you change it to `( .*? | \* | - )` it's useless.

Comment: @sln, where??  String REGEXP_STATUS=...

Comment: `"^(\\s*)(\\w+/\\d+|\\w+/\\d+/\\d+)(\\s+)(.*?)(notconnected|disabled|connected)(\\s+)(\\d+|trunk)(\\s+)(\\w+|a-\\w+)(\\s+)(\\w+|a-\\d+)(\\s+)(\\w+|/+).*"` is better. These alternation parts ( .*? | `\* | - )` will never be touched.

Comment: solution from @sln 
thank you

Comment: For sanity: this is a great example of "when not to use regular expressions". If you can't read your own regexp, write a normal string tokenizer. Is it more verbose? Absolutely. Is it easier to maintain? Forget about "easier", it _can_ be maintained, unlike this regexp, which you already had to ask SO for help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing it to use lazy quantifier `.*?` will fix it.
But, these alternation parts ( .*? `| \* | - )` will never be touched.

Here is a [readable](http://www.regexformat.com) fixed, version of your regex

```
 ^ 
 ( \s* )                                 # (1)
 ( \w+ / \d+ | \w+ / \d+ / \d+ )         # (2)
 ( \s+ )                                 # (3)
 ( .*? )                                 # (4)
 (                                       # (5 start)
      notconnected
   |  
      disabled
   |  
      connected
 )                                       # (5 end)
 ( \s+ )                                 # (6)
 ( \d+ | trunk )                         # (7)
 ( \s+ )                                 # (8)
 ( \w+ | a- \w+ )                        # (9)
 ( \s+ )                                 # (10)
 ( \w+ | a- \d+ )                        # (11)
 ( \s+ )                                 # (12)
 ( \w+ | /+ )                            # (13)
 .*
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 : len 87 ) 
 Fa0/1     --- Cisco IP phone -  notconnected   20       a-full    auto    10/100BaseTX  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 : len 1 ) 

 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 1 : len 5 ) 
Fa0/1  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 6 : len 5 ) 

 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 11 : len 22 ) 
--- Cisco IP phone -    
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 33 : len 12 ) 
notconnected  
 **  Grp 6 -  ( pos 45 : len 3 ) 

 **  Grp 7 -  ( pos 48 : len 2 ) 
20  
 **  Grp 8 -  ( pos 50 : len 7 ) 

 **  Grp 9 -  ( pos 57 : len 6 ) 
a-full  
 **  Grp 10 -  ( pos 63 : len 4 ) 

 **  Grp 11 -  ( pos 67 : len 4 ) 
auto  
 **  Grp 12 -  ( pos 71 : len 4 ) 

 **  Grp 13 -  ( pos 75 : len 2 ) 
10
```